# Selecting i for change of color

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a little script that changes the colours of the background and the input text based on the length of the input. I would like to make one change but I cannot figure out exactly how. Instead of changing the colour of the entire input text, I want to change only the letter that is changing the colour. So the letters change colour one by one. Below is the line I have and the element it is calling is "ids". I need to say something like "ins[i]" but I do not know how exactly. http://jsbin.com/janukece/1/edit

```
document.getElementById("ids").style.color= '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Styling is applied to HTML elements - letters aren't HTML elements, so you can't do it in a straight-forward manner as you imagined. Try something like

```
<span id="letter0">T</span><span id="letter1">E</span><span id="letter2">S</span><span id="letter3">T</span>
```

then apply styling to the `span` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have different multi-coloured letters in a simple input, but you can build this with the HTML5 contenteditable attribute and a span container for every letter.

This example uses jQuery:

```
// we have a hidden input field and a div container for our coloured letters.
// we change the colours when the hidden input looses focus (blur event)    
$("div").prop("contentEditable", true).blur(function(){
        // get text from the div
        var divText = $(this);

        //and split to an array
        var chars = divText.split("");

        // set text as input field value
        $("#hidden").val(divText);

        // clear the div container
        $(this).html("");

        // generate a span for each letter from chars array, colour it and append to the div
        $.each(chars, function(){
            $("<span>").text(this).css({
                color: "#"+(Math.random()*16777215|0).toString(16)
            }).appendTo("div");
        });
    });
```

This is shown in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Y8ySy/

Comment: if you can, it would be beneficial if you provided the OP with a vanilla solution as well. or at least describe what the code you have written does so he can press his/her own.